# Error "unable to find vcvarsall.bat" despite newest visual studio version

Tags: python, visual-studio, compiler-errors, kernel, cython

I'm working in Jupyter Notebook. When I want to compile a .pyx in cython, it throws an error similar to this:

```
%run -i setup.py build_ext --inplace

unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

The setup.py file looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("hh_vers_vector.pyx"),
)
```

This only happens, however, on my computer at work. At the one at home, it works just fine.

[image]

It is probably an issue with Visual Studio as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/). The thing is, I installed the very same version of Visual Studio 2017 Community on both computers. The latest Anaconda 3 version is installed on both computers. Both use Python 3.6.2 and IPython 6.1.0. So how can that be? Both run with Windows 10. I'll also show you my .pyx file. If you need more information I will edit my post.

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np
import time

def hhModel(*params, Iext, float dt, int Vref):

    ## Unwrap params argument: these variables are going to be optimized
    cdef float ENa = params[0]
    cdef float EK  = params[1]
    cdef float EL  = params[2]
    cdef float GNa = params[3]
    cdef float GK  = params[4]
    cdef float GL  = params[5]

    ## Input paramters
    # I    : a list containing external current steps, your stimulus vector [nA]
    # dt   : a crazy time parameter [ms]
    # Vref : reference potential [mV]

    def alphaM(float v, float vr):       return 0.1 * (v-vr-25) / ( 1 - exp(-(v-vr-25)/10) )
    def betaM(float v, float vr):        return 4 * exp(-(v-vr)/18)
    def alphaH(float v, float vr):       return 0.07 * exp(-(v-vr)/20)
    def betaH(float v, float vr):        return 1 / ( 1 + exp( -(v-vr-30)/10 ) )
    def alphaN(float v, float vr):       return 0.01 * (v-vr-10) / ( 1 - exp(-(v-vr-10)/10) )
    def betaN(float v, float vr):        return 0.125 * exp(-(v-vr)/80)

    ## steady-state values and time constants of m,h,n

    def m_infty(float v, float vr):      return alphaM(v,vr) / ( alphaM(v,vr) + betaM(v,vr) )
    def h_infty(float v, float vr):      return alphaH(v,vr) / ( alphaH(v,vr) + betaH(v,vr) )
    def n_infty(float v, float vr):      return alphaN(v,vr) / ( alphaN(v,vr) + betaN(v,vr) )

    ## parameters
    cdef float Cm, gK, gL, INa, IK, IL, dv_dt, dm_dt, dh_dt, dn_dt, aM, bM, aH, bH, aN, bN
    cdef float Smemb = 4000    # [um^2] surface area of the membrane
    cdef float Cmemb = 1       # [uF/cm^2] membrane capacitance density
    Cm = Cmemb * Smemb * 1e-8  # [uF] membrane capacitance

    gNa = GNa * Smemb * 1e-8   # Na conductance [mS]
    gK  = GK  * Smemb * 1e-8   # K conductance [mS]
    gL  = GL  * Smemb * 1e-8   # leak conductance [mS]

    # numSamples = int(T/dt);
    cdef int numSamples = len(Iext);
    # DEF numSamples = 200000

    # initial values
    cdef float[:] v = np.empty(numSamples, dtype=np.float)
    cdef float[:] m = np.empty(numSamples, dtype=np.float)
    cdef float[:] h = np.empty(numSamples, dtype=np.float)
    cdef float[:] n = np.empty(numSamples, dtype=np.float)
    #cdef float v[numSamples]
    #cdef float m[numSamples]
    #cdef float h[numSamples]
    #cdef float n[numSamples]

    v[0]  = Vref                    # initial membrane potential
    m[0]  = m_infty(v[0], Vref)     # initial m
    h[0]  = h_infty(v[0], Vref)     # initial h
    n[0]  = n_infty(v[0], Vref)     # initial n

    ## calculate membrane response step-by-step
    for j in range(0, numSamples-1):

        # ionic currents: g[mS] * V[mV] = I[uA]
        INa = gNa * m[j]*m[j]*m[j] * h[j] * (ENa-v[j])
        IK = gK * n[j]*n[j]*n[j]*n[j] * (EK-v[j])
        IL = gL * (EL-v[j])

        # derivatives
        # I[uA] / C[uF] * dt[ms] = dv[mV]
        dv_dt = ( INa + IK + IL + Iext[j]*1e-3) / Cm;

        aM = 0.1 * (v[j]-Vref-25) / ( 1 - exp(-(v[j]-Vref-25)/10))
        bM = 4 * exp(-(v[j]-Vref)/18)
        aH = 0.07 * exp(-(v[j]-Vref)/20)
        bH = 1 / ( 1 + exp( -(v[j]-Vref-30)/10 ) )
        aN = 0.01 * (v[j]-Vref-10) / ( 1 - exp(-(v[j]-Vref-10)/10) )
        bN = 0.125 * exp(-(v[j]-Vref)/80)

        dm_dt = (1-m[j])* aM - m[j]*bM
        dh_dt = (1-h[j])* aH - h[j]*bH
        dn_dt = (1-n[j])* aN - n[j]*bN

        # calculate next step
        v[j+1] = (v[j] + dv_dt * dt)
        m[j+1] = (m[j] + dm_dt * dt)
        h[j+1] = (h[j] + dh_dt * dt)
        n[j+1] = (n[j] + dn_dt * dt)

    return v
```

Comment: This is a bit of a guess but try adding `import setuptools` to your setup.py file. I believe it contains some code to help find vcvarsall.bat, and has worked for me in the past. You don't have to use the module once you've imported it

Comment: Thank you, I will try using it tomorrow and give feedback.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: No I didn't. It drove me crazy, I switched to a Linux Cluster my university offers.